# Given that the probability of winning roulette after 34 bets is more than 50% why do we loose at roulette?

Tags: probability

I am confused about the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070855/calculating-the-probability-of-winning-roulette-after-x-bets) about the probability of winning at roulette after 34 bets.

It explains that the probability of losing 34 bets in a row is  $(\frac{37}{38})^{34} $ If this does not happen then we have won at least once, gaining $35 and so we are ahead.

Thus the probability of being ahead is $1-(\frac{37}{38})^{34}=0.596$ so it looks like the house looses on average.

Yet I know that the house wins on average.

The probability of me winning is $\frac{35}{38} -\frac{37}{38} = \frac{-1}{19}$

What am I missing here?

Comment: You only get your money back 60% of the time. In the remaining 40% of cases, the house takes all your money and keeps it.

Comment: Right... just because you have a higher chance of having an "okay" outcome, the bad outcomes are *really bad* and so far outweigh the possible benefits.

Comment: Also, to emphasize... "*The probability of me winning is... $-\frac{1}{19}$*"  No, that is not a probability.  Probabilities are always between $0$ and $1$.  That is an *expected return* per time you play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing is that the loss is much greater than the gain.  You can have a bet that has a very high chance of being profitable, but if the loss that happens rarely is large enough the expectation value is negative.  If you place $34$ bets you lose $34$ when you lose them all, which has a probability of $0.404$.  Most of the time you win you only win $2$, though sometimes you win $38$ and sometimes even more.

You can use the linearity of expectation to compute the expectation.  The expectation of one bet is $35 \cdot \frac 1{38}-1\cdot \frac {37}{38}=-\frac 1{19}$ as you say.  The expectation of $34$ bets of $1$ each is then $-\frac {34}{19}$

As an extreme example, consider the following game:  We will roll a standard six sided die.  If it comes up $1,2,3$ or $4$ I will pay you $1$.  If it comes up $5$ or $6$ you pay me $100$.  Do you want to play?  You win $\frac 23$ of the time.

Comment: Playing the dice game? Thanks but no thanks ;-)